# How to show numbers on notification bar?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have app written with `Xamarin.Forms` for android and i would like to show a countdown from 30 seconds to 0 on the notification bar. I have seen some apps show temperature/internet peed but none of those are open source so i cant check how they have done it.

At this point i see the only way to for this is to make a icon .png file of each number and just use them from `Resouces/Drawables`. 
Is there any other way doing this?

Example with showing temperature:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot showing what you mean by the "notification bar"?

Comment: @hvaughan3 I added a example image with showing temperature on the notification bar.